# How to apply scale nine grid on graphic element without embedding source bitmapdata

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I have a runtime generated bitmapdata and want to apply scaleninegrid for it in my flex Skin class.I did it something like this:

```
  <fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        [Embed(source="progressBarTrack.png")]
        private var host:Class;

        [Bindable]
        private var texture:BitmapData

        protected function skin1_preinitializeHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            //here is just an example,my bitmapdata will be retrieved by an other way.
                          texture = Bitmap(new host()).bitmapData;
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:Graphic scaleGridBottom="11" scaleGridLeft="14" scaleGridRight="40" scaleGridTop="10">
    <s:Rect width="300" height="22">
        <s:fill>
            <s:BitmapFill source="{texture}"/>
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>
</s:Graphic>
```

However, it did not work no matter i set the width and height or not.I also tried to embed the source image,it worked,but as the bitmapdata is runtimely generated, i can not set the scalenine like @embed.....,scaleGridLeft.....

Is there anyway allows me to do that or anything wrong i did?i would like to get some tips before i hack into the source code,and make my own graphic element which supports it.

Many thanks!!!

Comment: Apparently you've tried to post an image - you cannot yet, you can post a link to it. Also, do you mind posting some code as how do you call `scale9grid()`?

Comment: Hi there, i think i did post code here,didn't i?

Comment: are you getting an error message when compiling or is bitmap displaying but not scaling correctly?

Comment: Hi Lee, the bitmap could be displayed , just was not "ninely" scaled, except i specified the grid with in the source field with @embed...,xxx. I digged into the code, seems somehow the graphics element did not draw the bitmap on their parent's body but on their own display object,i suppose,obviously that would make the scale does not work.   however, i just tried set the the element:"Rect" to use DisplayObjectSharingMode.USES_SHARED_OBJECT, but did not make any difference yet. still looking into it.

Comment: Did you try creating a `Sprite` object via pure code, slap there a Bitmap, then set `scale9Grid` property of the sprite to what you need? Also, `scale9Grid` only works if the object is scaled - is your object scaled?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [bytearray.org ScaleBitmap class](http://www.bytearray.org/?p=118). It's an open source class that extends BitmapData to render scale9 bitmaps at runtime.